# Python 2.7 Error al insertar un texto con ñ en una base de datos sql server

Tags: python, sql-server

Cuando intento insertar un registro que contiene un campo con la letra ñ en tabla pedidos de la base de datos del sql server

```
            #Insertamos información en la base de datos sql server
        personIp.execute("INSERT INTO pedidos (CODIGO,SERIE,DELEGACION,ALMACEN,FECHA,COMERCIAL,CLIENTE_CODIGO,CLIENTE_SERIE,CCC,FP,CP,TARIFA,DTOGEN,DTOPP,IVA,REC,PORTES,BRUTO,BASE,TOTAL,AGENCIA,OBS,PEDIDO_CLIENTE,CIP,CENTRO,CERRADO,BLOQUEADO,BLOQUEADO_MOTIVO,INVSUJETOPASIVO,BLOQUEO_ECONOMICO,WEB_ESTADO,USUARIO,DIRENVMER_DESTINATARIO,DIRENVMER_PAIS,DIRENVMER_PROV,DIRENVMER_POBLA,DIRENVMER_CP,DIRENVMER_DIREC,DIRENVMER_NUMERO,DIRENVFAC_DESTINATARIO,DIRENVFAC_PAIS,DIRENVFAC_PROV,DIRENVFAC_POBLA,DIRENVFAC_CP,DIRENVFAC_DIREC,DIRENVFAC_NUMERO) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (nuevo_codigo,pedido_serie,delegacion,almacen,fecha,comercial,cliente_codigo,cliente_serie,ccc,fpago,cpago,tarifa,dtogen,dtopp,iva,rec,portes,bruto,base,total,agencia,obs,pedido_cliente,cip,centro,cerrado,bloqueado,bloqueado_motivo,invsujetopasivo,bloqueo_economico,web_estado,usuario,empresa,pais,provincia,ciudad,codigo_postal,direccion,direnvmer_numero,noncomer,pais_fiscal,prov_fiscal,pobla_fiscal,cp_fiscal,direc_fiscal,direvfac_numero) )
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Estoy usando el modulo pyodbc

Comment: ¿Qué módulo python usas para interactuar con la base de datos?

Comment: EL modulo pyodbc

Comment: Aunque no he usado pyodbc ni sql server, y puedo estar equivocado, creo que el problema puede estar en que hayas declarado en la base de datos ciertos campos como de tipo SQLCHAR, los cuales solo admiten ASCII. Deberían ser SQLWCHAR para que admitan unicode (y teóricamente ya se ocupará pyodbc del encoding)

Comment: El problema es que no puedo modificar los campos de la base de datos. No tengo acceso a ella. Hay alguna forma de hacer que funcione sin modificar la base de datos

Comment: Prueba a poner una `u` delante de la cadena, es decir `u"INSERT INTO ..."`. Eso hace que la cadena sea de tipo "unicode". Tal vez en ese caso pyodbc la codifique en utf-8 para guardarla en la base de datos. Pero si la base de datos no está preparada para Unicode, se limitará a guardar los bytes recibidos "tal cual", sin información del encoding usado, lo que implica que tendrás que decodificar de nuevo esas cadenas cuando las recuperes de la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Probaste los encode, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-strings-decode-method/

Proba hacer un encode de la variable que vas a enviar al cursor antes de ejecutarlo, algo asi: variable.encode('utf-8')

Si no te funciona proba encode('latin1')

Uno de ellos deberia andar

Answer (score 0):

Yo diría que tú error no es de SQL Server.
Cuando tienes una tabla cuya intercalación de columna no contiene los carácteres que se insertan, no da un error de inserción. 
Como ejemplo

`create table ejemplo(valor char(1))
go
insert into ejemplo (valor)
values
('ñ')
go`

Ahora si realizó un select como mi intercalación es latin_general_ci_ai, me devuelve la ñ, pero:

```
create table ejemplo2(valor char(1) collate Estonian_CS_AS )
go
insert into ejemplo2
(valor)
values
('ñ');
```

Si ahora realizo un Select sobre esta columna el valor devuelto es un '?'

Simplemente lo ha encajado con otro carácter.

Si le pregunto a Sql server que carácter ascii tiene esos valores, el resultado es diferente, pero no ha generado un error. (241 en la primera tabla y 63 en la segunda).